# ??? Subscripted assignment mismatch error in MATLAB while defining a staggered grid

Tags: matlab, grid

```
function [x, y, z, u, v, w] = rectNSgrid()
global nX nY nZ nuX nvY nwZ h b l
b=input('Input channel width:');
h=input('Input channel height:');
l=input('Input channel length:');
nX = input('Input number of x divisions');
nY = input('Input number of y divisions');
nZ = input('Input number of z divisions');
x=zeros(nX,nY,nZ);
y=zeros(nX,nY,nZ);
z=zeros(nX,nY,nZ);
xu=zeros(nuX,nvY,nwZ);
yv=zeros(nuX,nvY,nwZ);
zw=zeros(nuX,nvY,nwZ);
for i = 1:nX
    x(i,:,:) = b*(i-1)/(nX-1);
end
for j = 1:nY
    y(:,j,:) = l*(j-1)/(nY-1);
end
for k = 1:nZ
    z(:,:,k) = h*(k-1)/(nZ-1);
end
nuX = nX-1;
nvY = nY-1;
nwZ = nZ-1;
for i=1:nuX
    xu(i,:,:) = (x(i,:,:)+x(i+1,:,:))/2; % Here is the place it shows the error
end
for j=1:nvY
    yv(:,j,:) = (y(:,j,:)+y(:,j+1,:))/2;
end
for k=1:nwZ
    zw(:,:,k) = (z(:,:,k)+z(:,:,k+1))/2;
end
```

And how do I plot the points of the grid in MATLAB? I need to solve the Navier-stokes equations on a rectangular rigid grid. The velocity control-volumes are shifted half a cell edge distance as the width of a x-CV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already said, this line cannot work :

```
xu(i,:,:) = (x(i,:,:)+x(i+1,:,:))/2;
```

because xu(i,:,:) is [1 nuy nuz] and x(i,:,:) is [1 ny nz] and ni nui are defined as different.

I think I understand what you would do, try this, maybe it will do your job :

```
function [x, y, z, u, v, w] = rectNSgrid(nX,nY,nZ,h,b,l)

% CELL NODES
[X Y Z] = meshgrid([0:b/nX:b],[0:l/nY:l],[0:h/nZ:h]);

% VELOCITY NODES
axX = [ 0.5*b/nX : b/nX : b-0.5*b/nX ];
axY = [ 0.5*l/nY : l/nY : l-0.5*l/nY ];
axZ = [ 0.5*h/nZ : h/nZ : h-0.5*h/nZ ];
[uX uY uZ] = meshgrid(axX,axY,axZ);

% PLOT
hold on; view(3); axis square;
plot3(X(:),Y(:),Z(:),'.b'); % CELL NODES
plot3(uX(:),uY(:),uZ(:),'.r'); % VELOCITY NODES
```

But pay attention, 'meshgrid' give you not exactly what you want as it indexes the X dimension in the 2th dimension of the resulting matrix and the Y in the first. Have a look at the documentation of 'meshgrid' for details. You can have it as you want with 'permute' I think.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The suggested code helps. But does it work equally well for a rectangular grid? I mean I used b=2, l = 290, h=1 (as per the dimensions of the channel I am using) and put nX=10; nY = 50 and nZ = 5. It does not show a very regular grid. Also I needed to ask, I needed the grid for solving the Navier-Stokes equation wherein each individual point in the grid would be assigned a particular position or velocity value. Is it possible doing that with the grid defined this way? Thanks.

Comment: It should work as fine with non-square grid, but with the 'axis square' you don't see it on the plot, put 'axis equal' instead. For storing your position (and velocity), just make a copy of X,Y,Z (and uX,uY,uZ) to store your data. Now for your Navier-Stokes problem, if you are solving it by finite differences, this way is very OK, if you plan to use finite elements, you rather need a triangulated mesh.

Comment: I am using finite differences only. So this works for me.. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you need to interpolate with interp2 in the line with the error, and play with permute to return temporarily to normal matrices.

How to interpolate is not specified in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not surprised because you are doing:

```
for i=1:nuX
    xu(i,:,:) = (x(i,:,:)+x(i+1,:,:))/2; 
end
```

but `x` is of size `(nX,nY,nZ)` so unless `nX = nuX`, you will have an error. Even if `nX = nuX`, you will still have an error due to `x(i+1,:,:)` when `i = nuX`.

Comment: You need to change the indexing of `x` in your code to make sure you are always between `1` and `nX` when `i` goes from `1` to `nuX`. This is difficult because you are using both `i` and `i+1` so I can't see how this can work.